# Why can't I use PLA with ABS in a dual extruding 3D printer?

Tags: pla, abs

I have a XYZ Da Vinci duo and I want to run water soluble PLA with ABS How can I do that?

Comment: PLA Is not water soluble, don't you mean PVA? Note PLA and ABS arre different materials requiring different temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: PLA is not water soluable.

Second: You want the melting points of the plastics to be as close as possible. PLA is printed between 180 and 200 °C. ABS is printed at 220 to 240 °C.

PVA on the other hand is water soluable and is printed in the same temperature range as ABS.

The setup is dependant on your slicer: you need to select one extruder as being the support structure one, the other as the main body one. Then you assign the filaments to them. Without knowing your slicer, I can't asnwer this better.

Comment: PVA adheres well to PLA, Nylon and CPE; adhering to TPU and and ABS is experimental.

Comment: While OP surely didn't mean PLA, 215 is in normal range of usable temperatures for PLA and 220 is probably not going to go badly wrong. 180 IMO is not usable; extrusion rate will be highly limited and pressure dependent.